# Windows 10 large Icons in Applications

Tags: windows-10, icons

I think I hit a keyboard shortcut or so, and all my icons in applications like outlook are really big. I tried the accessibility I tried the display settings, asked colleagues but nobody seems to know.
My text etc looks all normal but all surrounding toolbars have XL icons.

What could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: That appears normal for Office - Office Menus have become large recently. When you say you checked settings - Did you check Scaling?  Setting Scale to 125% to 150% will make icons and ribbons look much larger - especially 150%

Comment: It's touch friendly mode that you've enabled, and there are questions about this already, because I answered one of them lots of years ago. Lemme see if I can find it.

Comment: @john it isn't scaling. Scaling scales all elements consistently (in MS apps at least, Java is crap on that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ribbon Size in office 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/991252/ribbon-size-in-office-2016)

Comment: Scaling affects all elements including the Ribbon on my machines which I why I make the suggestion. Does not hurt to look and see.